# How to fully remove file in repository?

Tags: mercurial

I add a file with commit and push it to repository. If I remove the file with new commit, this file all the same will locates in repository (concept of version control systems). Can I delete this file from repository fully (File and all information about this file in a commit history)? I want remove it to have possibility to back on previous commit and haven't troubles with requirement of this file availability in repository.

Comment: Are you the only person with access to this repository or have the changesets with that file already been shared with other people?

Answer (score -1):

Make this command, to remove the files in repository

```
hg addremove
```

With the command hg status , you can see what will be remove, with **!** symbol before the file. For example

```
# hg status

! src/main/filex
! src/main/fileY
```